# "As such" to mean "like that"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 1- On any type of formal school exam, these sentences would not be
>   considered "correct" they are never written ***as such***.....they're
>   only spoken ***as such***.
>
> 2- Do not behave ***as such***.
>
> 3- Doing things ***as such*** will bring about disaster. Try to do
>   things a better way.

I have seen some speakers use "as such" this way. Are these sentences valid? Can I use "as such" to mean "like that"?

Comment: *As such* is a phrase that always refers to an antecedent.

Comment: So this usage is wrong then?